# Azure blob storage has been implemented but its content type in the cloud showing octet-stream issue

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

We have implemented azure blob storage plugin in our project, and we have uploading multiple extension files like image pdf etc to the cloud, but in the cloud it shows content type as octet-stream. i have tried setting content type in stream_flush method, but it doesnt work.

i have tried adding additional params to the azure api createBlockBlob but it doesnt take extra params.

which method of the stream i have to set the content type?
can anyone please suggest how to pass content type of the uploading file to the cloud ?

please help me to solve this issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Comment: You can set `Content-Type` when putting the BLOB or `x-ms-blob-content-type` when setting the BLOB's properties.

Comment: @volkerschulz, thanks for the reply, i had already resolved this.

Comment: @Thejaswini Glad to hear that. If your solution could be of use to others, why don't you post it as answer and accept it?